# Is it possible to implement a youtube video without the embed url?

Tags: html, youtube

I know it is generally essential essential to implement an `/embed/` URL to place a video on the page i.e. : 
`<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="640" height="390"
  src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?autoplay=1&origin=http://example.com"
  frameborder="0"/>`

My question today is, is it possible to implement it without the `/embed/` ?

i.e. https://youtu.be/M7lc1UVf-VE

The reasoning for this is within the system I have developed an individual accidentally used the whole youtube links rather than embed, I was thinking about making a parsing script with PHP but I'm sure theres an easier way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find the solution so I simply used the PHP equivalent as noted.

```
$raw = "https://youtu.be/M7lc1UVf-VE";
$url = str_replace($raw, "youtu.be/", "youtube.com/embed/");
```